# Toggle slide down for faqs

Tags: javascript, toggle, slidedown, toggleclass

I'm trying to set up a faqs page on the blog and struggling with getting the code right. Here's what I want to do > http://jsfiddle.net/qwL33/

Actually everything is alright but when clicking over the first part (let's suppose this is question 1), its opening up both parts (means both question). HELP.

Here's the code:

```js
    $('#slidetoggle')
      .on('click', function(e) {
        jQuery('.slider').toggle('slideDown');
      });
```

```html
<div id="slidetoggle">HELLO 1</div>
<div class="slider" style="display: none">Hello there!</div>

<div id="slidetoggle">HELLO 2</div>
<div class="slider" style="display: none">Hello there!</div>
```

Comment: post your code so we can help you, probably duplicate id or something like that... but if we dont see your code we cant help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by far this is not the best option, but your problem is that you are copying the same ID (slidetoggle), i have added the same function again and replace the id adding a 2, you can see it in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sw5ohfqv/
the best way would be to create a function that closes all the one visibles, and then opens the one clicked.

```
   $('#slidetoggle2')
.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $slider = $('.slider'),
        isOpened = $slider.is(':visible');

    if (isOpened)
    {
        $slider.slideUp();
        $this.text('show fields');
    }
    else
    {
        $slider.slideDown();
        $this.text('hide fields');
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh Thank you so very much. :)